# Comment "esprit cartésien" en est-il venu à être synonyme de "esprit logique" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

Descartes est pourtant le philosophe le moins logique qui soit, des prémices (si je dis "je pense, donc...", c'est que j'ai déjà supposé que "je suis"), aux conclusions (voir par exemple son explication de la circulation du sang, dans le Discours de la Méthode - que très peu lisent encore, heureusement).

Qui l'a promu à ce rang d'excellence, dont les Français sont fiers ?

*(Nota : cette dérision peut être due au fait que je suis aussi Britannique)*.

Comment: Peut être aussi êtes-vous un peu sévère avec Descartes ? Je ne peux pas vous donner l'histoire de l'usage de cette idée, mais quelques critiques, par descartes lui même, de cette idée : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum#Un_principe_.C3.A0_inscrire_dans_son_contexte

Comment: @Istao Merci de votre lien ; oui, j'en veux un peu à Descartes, de sa pensée prétentieuse dans le "Discours", et de l'attribution chauvine de la géométrie analytique (on disait beaucoup plus justement : "géométrie algébrique", inventée par Apollonios et reprise par les "Arabes" - en fait surtout les Perses)

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une question de langue. Une question intéressante au demeurant, mais hors-sujet ici.

Comment: This is a question about philosophy, not language.

Comment: @Romain Je ne sais pas si c'est off-topic car ça a un lien avec l’étymologie du mot.

Comment: @MarkThorin I think that if you are calling Descartes one of the least logical philosophers because of his claims, you should take into consideration his method.  His method is the basis of modern logic because it strips every extra assumption away and then begins from the bottom, looking at axiomatic facts and then builds up.  This is the basis of the modern scientific method.  Descartes does not already suppose in his work that he exists before he explains why.  If you are going to understand the connection between the two terms, you have to understand what logic is and his use of it.

Comment: @MarkThorin Also, the derisiveness of your post isn't welcome here.  If you want to know the etymology of term, ask about it.  If it seems contradictory, say so.  Leave out the derisiveness toward Descartes and also your implied derisiveness toward the French for valuing him so much.

Comment: Sorry to be late to answer : I was far away, without any connection. @Romain VALERI : You are right, I gave you two good marks, although I don't like the arrogance of a number of French people thinking that they have more perceptiveness than all others, and always referring to Descartes they have probably never read.

Comment: @Patrick Sebastien (cut because I couldn't answer both of you in one comment - it was rejected) : I strongly disagree, but this not a place to argue about philosophy - and I didn't "gave" you any bad marks !

Answer (score 9):

La méthode de Descartes s'appuie sur des principes qui consistent à privilégier la raison à la foi, l'analyse et la division de problèmes en plus petits plus faciles à résoudre et l'esprit de synthèse (du simple vers le complexe).

Il s'agit bien d'utiliser la logique pour expliquer les choses.

C'est donc naturellement qu'esprit cartésien est <s>synonyme de</s> apparenté à esprit logique. Les erreurs et approximations que ne manqueront pas de trouver dans ses ouvrages quelques perfides voisins ;-) ne remettent pas en cause ces principes eux-mêmes.

Answer (score 6):

L'expression « esprit cartésien » n'a rien à voir avec un quelconque « rang d'excellence ». Elle est en rapport avec sa philosophie, qui, que tu le veuilles ou non, s'appuie sur la logique.

Au début du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle, particulièrement en terre Catholique, la [scolastique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scolastique) domine. Il s'agit de s'appuyer sur la sagesse des anciens, en réconciliant la tradition chrétienne avec la lecture des philosophes grecs, notamment Aristote.

Descartes fait partie d'un courant qui promeut au contraire le raisonnement. Une chose est vraie non parce que les anciens l'ont dit, mais parce qu'on a pu la déduire en appliquant des méthodes de raisonnement. Descartes cherche à ramener la science à un raisonnement précis, mathématisé quand il peut, s'appuyant sur un petit nombre d'hypothèses intuitives ou empiriques. Il exclut toute connaissance qui ne rentre pas dans ce cadre.

L'« esprit cartésien » est celui qui applique les [*Règles pour la direction de l'esprit*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_R%C3%A8gles_pour_la_direction_de_l%27esprit), ou qui au moins en suit les grands principes, notamment :

- « Il ne faut nous occuper que des objets dont notre esprit paraît capable d’acquérir une connaissance certaine et indubitable. »
- « II faut chercher sur l’objet de notre étude, non pas ce qu’en ont pensé les autres, ni ce que nous soupçonnons nous-mêmes, mais ce que nous pouvons voir clairement et avec évidence, ou déduire d’une manière certaine. C’est le seul moyen d’arriver à la science. »
- « Pour compléter la science il faut que la pensée parcoure, d’un mouvement non interrompu et suivi, tous les objets qui appartiennent au but qu’elle veut atteindre, et qu’ensuite elle les résume dans une énumération méthodique et suffisante. »

Un « esprit cartésien » n'est pas n'importe quel « esprit logique », les deux termes ne sont pas synonymes. Un esprit cartésien s'appuie entièrement sur la logique pour viser une connaissance complète.

Comment: Pour Descartes, "l'intuition est la connaissance immédiate et certaine de la vérité d'une idée par sa nécessité intrinsèque, comme on le saisit dans les mathématiques et plus encore dans l'intuition que la conscience a d'elle-même d'être une « chose pensante » à travers l'expérience du cogito." (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuition) voila ce qui fait la différence entre la pure logique et Descartes : la raison ne peut que contrôler, mettre en mots ce qui est perçu, dé-couvert par l'intuition.