# Quelle préposition utiliser avec « chercher » ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes

Je connais « chercher » et « chercher à ». Le second a les synonymes tels que « tâcher de » et « se hasarder à ». Toutefois, comment comprendre **chercher sur** ? Dans les deux mentions suivantes, pourquoi utiliser **chercher sur** et pas « chercher » ni «  chercher (une autre préposition) » ?

Voici [un exemple de Thomas Corneille](http://books.google.com/books?id=SPpEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA531&dq=%22Se%20dit%20lorsqu%27on%20veut%20tracer%20&%20d%C3%A9crire%20un%20arc%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v2t8UrPlIYLriAfb6YDgCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Se%20dit%20lorsqu%27on%20veut%20tracer%20&%20d%C3%A9crire%20un%20arc%22&f=false).

> Tracer en cherche, Se dit lorsqu'on veut tracer & décrire un arc qui ne se peut faire que par des points trouvés. Pour rapporter ensemble toute la **cherche sur** l'ouvrage, on se sert de la ligne ou du cordeau, qui est étendu d'un bout de la cherche à l'autre. On passe dans le cordeau de petits morceaux de bois dressés à plomb, & dont unes des extrémités aboutit à la courbe de la cherche.

Et voici [un autre exemple de Descartes](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7776/comment-esprit-cartesien-en-est-il-venu-a-etre-synonyme-de-esprit-logique/7795#7795).

> II faut **chercher sur** l’objet de notre étude, non pas ce qu’en ont pensé les autres, ni ce que nous soupçonnons nous-mêmes, mais ce que nous pouvons voir clairement et avec évidence, ou déduire d’une manière certaine. C’est le seul moyen d’arriver à la science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans la citation du *Dictionnaire universel des arts et des sciences*, le mot *cherche* est un nom et non une forme verbale. Le nom *[cherche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cherche)* a disparu en français moderne : c'est la forme *recherche* qui s'est imposée. Ici, *cherche* est employé dans un sens technique qui n'a à priori rien à voir avec *recherche* (défini dans la citation, et seul mentionné par la [quatrième édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/cherche) du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* ; en français moderne, on n'utilise que la forme *[cerce](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cerce)* (et ce n'est qu'un terme technique guère connu en dehors des professions qui l'utilisent).

Dans la citation de Descartes, il faut considérer indépendamment le verbe *chercher* et le complément introduit par *sur*, qui indique le domaine de la recherche. Chacun a son sens habituel (*chercher* a le sens de l'anglais *search*). « L’objet de notre étude » est le domaine de la recherche ; en français moderne, on préfèrerait la préposition *dans*. L'objet cherché (complément d'objet direct du verbe *chercher*) est l'énumération « non pas ce qu’en ont pensé les autres, ni ce que nous soupçonnons nous-mêmes, mais ce que nous pouvons voir clairement et avec évidence, ou déduire d’une manière certaine ». C'est la même construction parfaitement ordinaire que dans « chercher un mot dans le dictionnaire » ou « chercher une rue sur une carte ».

Answer (score 0):

On cherche des poux *sur* la tête des autres, et on cherche une aiguille *dans* une botte de foin.

L'emploi de *sur* ou *dans* dépend du contexte, ici une surface ou un volume.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé.